# Один порт для socket.io и apache

Tags: сокет

Здравствуйте, как сделать один пор для socket.io и apache, т.е 80 порт. Если в настройках socket.io указать 80, то он не будет работать.

Comment: @alexyx5657, не очень понятно. 

Вы хотите, чтобы 2 разные программы получали соединения с одного и того же TCP порта?

Comment: разве это не возможно?

Comment: > разве это не возможно?  

разумеется нет.

Comment: как же тогда на других сайта используется http://site.com/socket.io/socket.io.js вместо http://site.com:порт/socket.io/socket.io.js

Comment: прокси, типа nginx либо на самой ноде.

интересный вопрос, можно ли такое сделать с пом-ю connmark ? типа сначала в юзерспейсе читаем заголовки, а потом с пом-ю connmark отправляем на нужный порт, правда непонятно как заставить приложение при этом подхватить соединение... может симуляцией, типа отправляем запрос сразу на оба порта, но handshake делаем поддельный, а потом просто рвем ненужное соединение... сдается мне что стандартными средствами OS такое не сделать.

Comment: например так:  

nginx.conf 
        
        #node
 location /socket.io {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
 }
        #apache
        location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
        }

Answer (score 1):

Опять коммент маловат...

IMHO (в *nix, про винду не знаю) `bind` для второго сокета на тот же порт OS сделать не позволит. Поэтому физически `listen/accept` должна делать только одна программа.

Если обработчик запроса может работать с клиентом по stdin/stdout, то можно использовать inetd (xinetd). На каждое новое соединение будет запускаться новый процесс.

А в принципе, полученный от `accept` сокет (конкретное соединение) можно передать уже работающему на том же хосте процессу, причем *не обязательно своему потомку*, по `sendmsg` . В этом случае "слушатель" и "обработчик" должны быть запрограммированы соответствующим  образом.

**UPDATE**

Хотел уже поподробнее описать эту интересную тему (передача файлового дескриптора между процессами), но обнаружил, что [все уже написано до нас...](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~eweiss/222_book/222_book/0201433079/ch17lev1sec4.html).

IMHO очень полезная ссылка.

Comment: т.е. можно не проксировать ? а установить соединение и передать его ? правильно я понимаю что апач такое не умеет самостоятельно ? а можно пример какого-нить приложения что так умеет делать ?

Comment: Про апач ничего не скажу. 

Пример - [Unix socket magic](http://www.lst.de/~okir/blackhats/node121.html).

Этот прием рекомендуют в Линукс (параноидальная забота о безопасности) для приема соединений по привелигированным портам (1-1023). Обработка предполагается в изначально не рутовом процессе.

Comment: чет я почитал почитал и до конца не уверен - так установивший соединение процесс может выйти или хотя-бы закрыть сокет ?

Comment: Да, конечно может. Связь принявшего сокет с клиентом не оборвется.

--

Тут действительно "немножко магия". Вкратце:

Процесс отправляющий сокет (по сути файловый дескриптор) через sendmsg(fd, msg, ...) как бы просит ядро сделать dup этого дескриптора (отправляемого в msg), только не для себя, а для приемника.

После этого отправитель может закрыть отправленный дескриптор.

Результат этого dup-а заносится ядром в таблицу дескрипторов приемника при recvmsg и передается ему в recvmsg().

Теперь с ним можно работать как обычно, как будто он был получен, например, от accept.

Comment: а типа как хардлинка в файлухе...

Comment: Наверное, можно и так сказать. Мне такая аналогия в голову не приходила.

--

Я как-то делал (правда проект загнулся...) эту штуку для сервера, который должен был держать тысячи соединений. Проблема здесь в том, что количество дескрипторав одного процесса ограничено (default 1024), а плодить тысячи процессов (по одному на connect) накладно.

Поэтому был один прцесс, который принимал соединения и разбрасывал их нескольким (десяткам) многопоточных обработчиков. В них каждый connect "жил" в своем thread. Соответственно обработчики сообщали главному о количестве дескрипторов... 
(места мало...).

Comment: @eicto, ну как, разобрались? Я в update ответа хорошую ссылочку добавил.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью настроек веб-сервера (apache, nginx, ...) можно сделать двухсторонне проксирование типа:

```
mysyte.com/socket <==> mysite.com:8080
```

этот способ в свое время мне помог в аналогичном случае.